# ASP.Net GridView styling - invisible cell lining

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I`m using a Gridview in an ASP.Net web app.
Since it has custom styling and templates, I couldn't figure how to style it the way I want. I want all the lines of the final HtmlTable to be invisible - just purely the cellcontent and margins between them, without a visible table. How can I do such a thing?

The gridView itself:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="Items" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView 
ID="Items" runat="server" GridLines="None" 
CellSpacing="Set a Value" CellPadding="Set a Value">
</asp:GridView>
```